# Prevent certain elements from receiving focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

So I have the following function. What it does is listens for the focus event on all elements. If that element is either in `$mobileMenu` or `$menuItems` it permits it otherwise it removes the focus:

```
var $body = $("body");
var $mobileMenu = $("#mobile-menu");
var $menuItems = $("#main-menu a");

$body.on("focus.spf", "*", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $this = $(this);

  // Prevent items from recieving focus and switching view
  if (!$this.is($mobileMenu) && !$this.is($menuItems)) {
    $this.blur();
  } else {
    console.log(this);
  }
})
```

The issue I have is that this prevents the user from focusing on anything whatsoever if a normally focusable element that is now non-focusable precedes any of my white-listed elements as it just attempts to refocus on the same element over and over again.

Does anyone know how I can tell it to instead skip to the next focusable element?

Comment: Maybe it's the placement of the ``stopPropogation()`` statement? I'm a  little confused by what you said right after the code.

Comment: @itdoesntwork `stopPropagation()` is good because we don't want to bubble up and waste resources. Basically the internal tab index gets reset on `blur()` so each time you tab it attempts to focus on the first tabbable element which gets blurred and the next time you tab it tries to select it again.

Comment: e.preventDefault() could help ?

Comment: @Eric Doesn't prevent the focus event I'm afraid.

Comment: I have to point out, this approach could make the page unusable for people using screen readers. Trying to control the focus can interfere with the keyboard focus, hindering people from accessing the rest of the page.

Comment: @AlastairC This is for a mobile slide out menu and only prevents focus when it is open. It also allows the close and menu structure to be focused only during that period. So it kind of makes sense.

Comment: You might want to test it with VoiceOver on iOS then, just to check.

Comment: @AlastairC shall do, it is for a design agency so screen-readers are unlikely to be our target audience anyhow :P. They'll have to trigger the mobile media-queries as well which is unlikely I think.

Comment: An iPhone with VoiceOver would trigger media queries. Just mentioned as the question was tagged with accessibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works (updated) :

```
$body.on("focus.spt", "*", function(e){
  $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.is($mobileMenu) && !$this.is($menuItems)) {
    $this.blur();
    var next=$this.nextAll().find('a,input');
    if (next.length>0) next[0].focus();
  } else {
    console.log('ok',this);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
})
```

(updated) fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/CADjc/**
You can see in the console which elements that receives focus `(main-menu a` and `mobile-menu`)

Tested on :

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" value="test">
<span><input type="text" tabindex="2" value="test"></span>
<div><input type="text" id="mobile-menu" tabindex="3" value="mobile-menu"></div>
<div><span>
    <div id="main-menu">
        <a tabindex="4">main-menu</a>
        <a tabindex="5">main-menu</a>
    </div>
</span></div>
<span>
<input type="text" tabindex="6" value="test">
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks... but this only works because the elements are directly next to each other (otherwise `next()` doesn't work) in flow ... see http://jsfiddle.net/e96EV/2/

Comment: @GeorgeReith you are right, were blindly testing on the selfmade test markup, you _could_ have provided a markup example :) - see update above, and the updated fiddle as wel. Why do you close your markup eg <input ../> ?? (saw that in your fiddle update)

Comment: Just realised it only works if the allowed focusable element is the first focusable element in it's parent... see http://jsfiddle.net/CADjc/2/ - This is because of `next[0]` I believe which only tests the first found element. Also I closed the elements because JSfiddle has a hard time syntax highlighting unclosed elements (even if valid).

Comment: Ok I have fixed the `next[0]` but it still doesn't wrap around. Once it gets to the end it just switches between the last two... http://jsfiddle.net/CADjc/3/

Comment: Change was necessary because if it doesn't get a focusable element at `next[0]` it will just propagate and ignore any other potential sibling elements. Another issue is it will select sibling elements that are later in the DOM sooner than child elements.

Comment: `this.blur()` would also work as the method exists on elements themselves these days.

Answer (score 16):

### Set the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute to `-1`

`tabindex='-1'` will ignore focusable tabbing, which mean the focus will skip to the next focusable element, if any such exists.

```html
<input/>
<input tabindex='-1' value='tabindex set to -1'/>
```

This does not prevent direct focusing by clicking on the input element, because a user can still edit the field, and it has to be focused in order to be editable.

---

### Set [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert) attribute:

```html
<input/>
<input inert value='cannot be focused nor edited'/>
```

---

The reason there are 2 inputs in the above examples is to have the first one focusable so it's obvious when clicking the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key the next input won't get focus.

Comment: It's an standard solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Unnecessary update from vsync on this answer. It overcomplicates the original answer given.

Answer (score 5):

If you make something disabled, it won't receive focus.  For example:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Do add it programmatically, you could do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('disableme');
el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Disabled input elements aren't sent to the server when the form is submitted. Doesn't have to do much with the current scenario, but good to keep in mind.

Comment: My advice would be to replace the word "something" with "a form element", because `disabled` only applies to form elements, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

attr("readonly","readonly"), prevent input focus and value ARE send to the server.

Comment: No, the `readonly` attribute *does not* prevent the element receiving focus, either by tabbing to it or by clicking on it.  It prevents only editing the element's value.

Answer (score 2):

CSS-only solution from one of my past projects

```css
/* Prevents all mouse interactions */
.disabled-div {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Prevents all other focus events */
.disabled-div:focus,
.disabled-div:focus-within {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Only Disable with Prevent Focus</h1>

<input placeholder="Normal text field">
<br><br>
<input class="disabled-div" placeholder="Disabled text field">
<br><br>
<input placeholder="Normal text field">
<br><br>
<input class="disabled-div" placeholder="Disabled text field">
<br><br>
```

Flickers slightly when it receives focus. That is because when it receives focus, visibility is set to 'hidden' and focus is lost and visibility is set back to 'visible' again. This is actually good because the user now has some idea where focus is while going over disabled fields...

Comment: This is neat but unfortunately doesn't work on Safari or Firefox.

Comment: I wish this worked but turning off visibility doesn't impact focus at all in some browsers. I think any behavior you're seeing to the contrary is nonstandard.