# jquery if tab key pressed in text input, skip following input and go to next

Tags: jquery, input

I have some text inputs. If I tab from the #input1, I want to skip #input2 and go to next.

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="input1" class="control-label col-sm-4">Input 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control" id="input1" tabindex="3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2" class="control-label col-sm-4">Input 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="form-control" tabindex="4">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This field isn't always visible and is dependent on a select list option -->
<div class="form-group required" style="display:none">
    <label for="input3" class="control-label col-sm-4">Input 3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="input3" class="form-control" id="input3" tabindex="5">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="withdrawal_amount" class="control-label col-sm-4">Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="label" class="form-control" id="label" tabindex="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

I was targeting the focus to #label but if #input3 is visible I need to target that instead.

```
$('#withdrawal_amount').focusout(function() {
    $(window).keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 9) {
            $(this).next(':input').not('#input2').focus();
            // $('#label').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

I thought about seeing in #input3 is visible and set focus to that. What is the best way?

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE.**

I want to allow focus to the input#2 but I don't want the tab key to focus to the field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent certain elements from receiving focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962020/prevent-certain-elements-from-receiving-focus)

Comment: @SurjitSD, it's not a duplicate. I want to ALLOW focus to that input, NOT just using the tab key

Comment: Your question says "I want to skip #input2 and go to next." ? are you not trying to skip input? Clear me if I have mistaken

Comment: I only want to skip that input if the tab key was pressed in #input1. I need to allow focus at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown instead of keyup https://jsfiddle.net/09tchwx9/4/

```
 $(':text').keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which,
    ind = $(':text').index(this),
    skip=$(':text').eq(ind+1)
    if(key==9 && skip.hasClass('skip')){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(':text:not(.skip)').filter(function(i){return i> ind}).eq(0).focus();
  }
});
```